# Find phone number from given string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string

I have one resume , i want to find user's contact number(Mobile no or Phone no)
from the resume, Need any idea or solution or any assistance for achieving the goal .

What i Have tried so far....

```
var numString = "";
        string strData = ",38,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,382350,,,,,0,,,,8141884584,,,,,,,,";
        char[] separator = new char[] { ',' };
        string[] strSplitArr = strData.Split(separator);
        for (int q = 0; q < strSplitArr.Length; q++)
        {
            if (strSplitArr[q] != "")
            {
                int no = 0;

                no = strSplitArr[q].Length;
                if (no >= 10 && no <= 12)
                {
                    numString += strSplitArr[q].ToString() + ", ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Izzy please see the updated post

Comment: Just use a regex pattern like `,[\d]{10},`

Comment: Your example data doesn't look like a resume.  Is there a reason you are showing us code that is splitting a CSV string?  FYI that code can be reduced to `var numString = string.Join(", ", strData.Split(',').Where(s => s.Length >= 10 && s.Length <=12));`

Comment: any example code with urs given pattern @MacroMan

Comment: @juharr my approach is bad i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you use [Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is a sample code to find US Phone numbers:

```
string text = MyInputMethod();
const string MatchPhonePattern =
       @"\(?\d{3}\)?-? *\d{3}-? *-?\d{4}";

        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchPhonePattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        // Report the number of matches found.
        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;


        //Do something with the matches

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            //Do something with the matches
           string tempPhoneNumber= match.Value.ToString(); ;

         }
```

Comment: is there are different pattern for eeach country ?

Comment: It depends on the format of the phone numbers. But I have used this one for other countries too:

`@"\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})"`